# IntelliJ Start Failed on Mac OS after Update

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2016

I just update the IntelliJ IDEA a few minutes ago and now I got the error below when start de software.

**ERROR**:

```
Internal error. Please report to http://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-
errors

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager
at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:222)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at com.intellij.ide.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:36)
at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:78)
```

**INTELLIJ IDEA**
Version 2017.3.2 (IC-173.4127.27)

**MAC OS YOSEMITE**
Version 10.10.5

Anyone have a clue about how to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Please do what the error message tells you to do, and contact JetBrains support.

Comment: I already did it. Thank you!

Comment: @MarcosLeonel: Could you add a link to the ticket you created? Could be useful for people googling the error message and arriving here.

Comment: The support answer said exactly what @Herter said: "If after restart issue remains, please re-install from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/ "

Comment: @Henrik Request (#1220615):
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/1220615

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest reinstalling IDEA. Perhaps download the installer from their website first from http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html

The issue is most likely cause by the update screwing up the rights of some of the files. It is probably possible to fix this, but a reinstall is easier and faster so just do that.